# WPF drawing performance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been doing a lot of reading into WPF drawing and performance and it's apparent that some methods of drawing are better than others.  I have however gotten confused with different people's terminology of things and just want to clarify one issue.

The system I'm working on has lots of gauges on a screen (exactly like a speedometer in a car). The scale and range indicators can change and are different on each gauge. Is it best to draw these in the xaml or in the .cs file behind it. The reason I'm asking is that we are starting to see performance issues in the system when a lot of gauges are on display and I'm trying to isolate the cause.

Currently it's drawn behind with each individual segment added like `children.add(UIElement)`.

Comment: See [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) and [Drawing Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619.aspx) and related articles an MSDN.

Comment: You see performance issues when 'alot of gauges are on display'? What is 'alot'?

Comment: anything over 20 - 25, looking at the number of children on the page is about 70 with the scale etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if placing them in the xaml or the code behind makes a difference - at the end of the day these objects get pushed onto the visual layer one way or another.

Your issue is more likely because you're using fully blown **UIElement** instances.

For performance enhancements, try using more light-weight objects, i.e. [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

These objects are not as powerful as UIElements, so you may lose some functionality that you want to use that you'll need to reimplement another way.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation should put you on the right track.